# Paging for SPFx Solutions with PnP Pagination Control using ES6 or Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spfx, pnp-js

All the PnP Pagination example use React code ([example 1](https://spknowledge.com/2022/10/01/pnp-react-controls-part-5-pnp-paging-control/), [example 2](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/paging-for-spfx-solutions-with-pnp-pagination-control/), [example 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvv0xvfW9oU)) Does anyone know how to use PnP pagination using vanilla JS or ES6 with SPHttpClient? I am using no-framework SPFx and I don't want to convert my code to React.